# Кто - код текстового редактора или функция операционной системы - интерпретирует управляющие символы 0x00-0x1f (например, LineFeed, 0x0a)?

Tags: редактор-текста, ttf

кто разбирается в устройстве текстовых редакторов, подскажите, пжста.

1) Кто - код текстового редактора или функция операционной системы - интерпретирует управляющие символы 0x00-0x1f (например, LineFeed 0x0a)? Если эти символы имеют глифы в .ttf-файлах, и мы хотим видеть эти глифы в текстовом редакторе, изменения должны быть внесены в текстовый редактор или системную функцию?

2) Тот же вопрос по управляющим символам 0x80-0x9f.

3) Обратный вопрос: кто интерпретирует код 0x20 (Space) как знак переноса текста на новую строку? Чтобы изменить код Space'а на другой (например, на 0x49), где должны быть внесены изменения?

4) Чтобы проинтерпретировать старый печатный символ (например, 0x48) как управляющий (например, как LineFeed), где должны быть внесены изменения?

5) Для символов 0x00-0x7f, какие есть способы использовать 7-битную кодировку с классическим .ttf-файлом без конвертирования текста в 8-битную кодировку?

P.S.
Причины вопросов:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu8W0uobvQs

(печатные символы 0x00-0x46, управляющие 0x47 till 0x7f)
https://sun9-70.userapi.com/c855016/v855016873/147e35/y2yzXkm-EvQ.jpg

Comment: Опишите причины вопросов в самом вопросе, не всем интересно слушать лекцию про изобретенный вами алфавит. К тому же, по правилам сайта вопрос должен быть максимально самодостаточным, поэтому вся основная информация (в данном случае - какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить) должна быть в самом вопросе, а не по ссылкам.

Comment: не слушайте: ссылки для любознательных и для понимания поднимаемых вопросов не нужны. На вопросы ответить можете?

Comment: не слушайте: ссылки - мотивационная часть, и для понимания вопросов не нужны. На вопросы можете ответить? в т.ч. на:

Comment: 6) Растеризатор .ttf-данных (в т.ч. подпрограмма субпиксельной графики) - это часть ОС, верно?

Редактор вызывает растеризатор для каждого символа по-отдельности?
И делает это в графическом (а не текстовом) режиме?

Comment: Еще раз: сейчас в вопросе отсутствует важная часть - **какую конкретно проблему вы хотите решить**. Скорее всего вы не с той стороны подходите к проблеме, и не нужно модифицировать ни обработку кодов 0x00-0x1f, ни 0x80-0x9f, ни прочего, а каким-то образом добавить свою кодовую страницу (или как это называется) в utf. Про 7-8 битные кодировки при добавлении нового типа письменности лучше забыть.